# Como fazer com que um Link acione uma função javascript sem redirecionamento?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estava tentando fazer com que ao clicar em um **Link** `HTML <a></a>` executa-se uma função javascript, tive a priori a seguinte ideia atrelar um atributo `onclick` na tag `<a>` desta forma:

```
<a href="#" onclick="funcao()">OnClick</a>
```

Porem deste modo há ao ser clicado a página volta ao topo do scroll.

**Pergunta:** Como acionar uma função javascript sem haver este scroll (sem haver qualquer efeito, transparente para o usuário)?

Comment: `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="funcao()">OnClick</a>`, não lembro agora, mas desta forma não funciona?

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert não testei desta forma :-(

Comment: @Sanção, não conhecia os [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events), já valeu o dia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como a pergunta não possui uma tag jQuery, então resolvi adicionar esta resposta em contraste a do Ricardo.

```js
var meuLink = document.getElementById("meuLink");
meuLink.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<a id="meuLink" href="http://pt.stackoverflow.com/">Stackoverflow em Portugues</a>
```

Então para cancelar o redirecionamento, você apenas precisa adicionar a seguinte linha no corpo do metodo:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Boa resposta, não adicionei jquery por displicencia, mas já o fiz, na minha resposta usei jquery e somente javascritp, (eu fiz e respondi minha pergunta :-) ). +10

Comment: @Ricardo, eu particularmente não de JavaScript inline (problemas com legibilidade, acessibilidade, tamanho da pagina, falta de cache, e manutenibilidade), então não usuaria `href="javascript:funcao()"` ou `onclick="funcao"`, outro ponto do `return false;` do `jQuery`, é que ele faz uso de um `event.preventDefault()` e do `event.stopPropagation()`, e neste caso apenas o `preventDefault` é necessário e o `stopPropagation` pode vir a introduzir problemas.

Answer (score 2):

Pode-se usar basicamente duas formas:

```
<a href="javascript:funcao()">Href</a>
```

Indicar que deseja executar uma função javascript no atributo `href`.

OU

Adicionar um `id` ao link

```
<a href="#" id="executa-funcao">ID</a>
```

e usar um listener atrelado ao `id`

> OBS: Adicionar um `return false;` para que não haja o sequencia no comportamento padrão do link, neste caso o redirecionamento para o topo do documento.

```
$('#executa-funcao').click(function(){
    //FAZ ALGUMA COISA
    return false;
});
```